# mendix Swagger REST Webservice in UAT/PROD

Tags: rest, web-services, swagger, mendix

Hi I am working on the mendix rest webservices and through swagger , i can test the local host data all right.
But when i promote objects to acceptance, i need to update the webservice seurity to 'Requires authentication'. This would need username and password.

when the webservices are in the UAT, it fails to autheticate the request [image] as below shown. Can you please help if you have a solution in this situation?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the Path based access restrictions in your cloud environment. Allow all access to the appropriate paths as below to verify your endpoints.

[image]

Restart your application after applying the changes.